# Put an element of <td> always on top not in center

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 2 columns

```
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="menupage" >
            ...
            ...
        </div>
    </td>

    <td align="center"  >   

        <div id="contentpage" >
            ...
            ...
        </div>

    </td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to keep always in top not in center if the size of `<div id="contentpage" >` is big

Comment: Don't use tables for layout. Tables are intended for tabular data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `CSS` `vertical-align` property to align the `TD` contents to the `TOP`:

> vertical-align:top;

See this working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/PSrcS/)!

**e.g.,**

```
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;">
      <div id="menupage">
        ...
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" style="vertical-align:top;">   
      <div id="contentpage" >
        ...
      </div>
    </td>   
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably are looking at `valign` or `vertical-align`.

```
<td align="center" valign="top">
    <div id="contentpage">
    </div>
</td>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/Y84pS/

Note that `valign` is a [deprecated attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#adef-valign) (so are `align` and `border`. See [Index of Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html) for a complete list.). The recommended way to get these functionality is via CSS, using `vertical-align`, `text-align` and `border`.

The second table in my jsfiddle example uses CSS, and gets the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use tables then you might as well just use `valign`.

eg: `<div id="menupage" valign="top">`

If you want to use CSS you can use `vertical-align`.

You could set all td's in your stylesheet like so:

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I've no idea of your experience etc so I won't go on, but you should avoid tables for layout. You'll save yourself a lot of downvotes and "don't use tables" comments.